# Routing error - No subscribers were found. WCF-SQL Adapter

Tags: wcf, routes, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I'm attempting to call a Stored proc, get some data back, map that to the desired schema, output the result.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> The Messaging engine failed to process a message submitted by
>   adapter:WCF-SQL Source
>   URL:mssql://master-biztalk//ReportServer?InboundId=batman. Details:The
>   published message could not be routed because no subscribers were
>   found. This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port
>   has not been enlisted, or if some of the message properties necessary
>   for subscription evaluation have not been promoted. Please use the
>   Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.

I'm not quite certain why I'm getting this error. Searching the web hasn't enlightened me any further. Following are some of the steps I've undertaken

1. Consume adapter = generated schema.
2. Map this schema to desired output.
3. Receive port in the Orchestration which connects to a receive message which has the Schema generated by the consume adapter as the type.
4. Added a receive port in Biztalk, configured WCF-SQL and setup bindings. (Typed polling)
5. Linked this receive port to the logical receive port in orchestration.
6. I haven't promoted any elements in messages.

Thanks for the help

EDIT: I updated the pipeline to XML, and now I'm getting the following error:

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline:
>   "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive,
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Receive
>   Port: "DatabaseReceiveport" URI:
>   "mssql://master-biztalk//ReportServer?InboundId=batman" Reason:
>   Finding the document specification by message type
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/batman#TypedPolling"
>   failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.

I'm not quite sure what it's trying to do above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that either:

1. The Project/Assembly with the specified Schema has not been deployed.
2. The WCF SQL configuration is off somehow, frequently the InBoundId parameter.  That's where "batman" would come from.

In the All Artifacts Application, check the Schemas folder for that Schema by Root Node and Namespace.

Comment: I've checked the InboundId of consume adapter and the InboundId of the Receive port, both are the same. I also checked the Artifacts application and all the schemas in project are there. But the 'schema' specified in the error isn't really a schema :/

Comment: What do you mean by 'isn't really a schema'?

Comment: I might have misunderstood. The error message doesn't specify any schema names, does it? I assume it's trying to find schema of type: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/batman#TypedPolling"  Please correct me if I'm wrong. What's it trying to do atm, do you happen to know? Has it connected to the DB and executed the SP call, and then it's trying to output the data to the generated schema and it can't find this schema?

Comment: For Typed Polling, the root node name is always TypedPolling.  The namespace is a combination of http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling + the InboundId URI parameter.  You should be able to find these in the Schemas list in All Artifacts.  Check the Root Name and Target Namespace columns.

Comment: Thanks boatseller. I've nothing similar to that. schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo. I cant find any  schemas which has InboundId specified anywhere.

Comment: I had a quick look at the BizTalkNMgmtDb database as suggested here: http://abdulrafaysbiztalk.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/verifyingschemas-after-deployment/ and I can see the schema which I'm trying to call in the stored proc:http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo#GetRolesAdminResponse

Comment: Perhaps the Root Reference (on the <Schema> node) was mistakenly set.  If so, that will mask all other root definitions in the .xsd.

Comment: Just to update on this, I created a new project which was similar, and it worked fine.